# Parsing of "case" constants in Switch statements does not make sense

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

Can someone explain to me the behaviour of the second switch statement in this code:

```
function weird()
{
    $l_ret= [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Abort
    "Begin Switch OK"
    switch( $l_ret )
    {
        ([System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Abort)  { 'Abort'  }
        ([System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel) { 'Cancel' }
    }
    "End Switch OK"
    "Begin Switch BAD"
    switch( $l_ret )
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Abort  { 'Abort'  }
        [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel { 'Cancel' }
    }
    "End Switch BAD"
}
```

If I invoke `weird`, I get:

```
Begin Switch OK
Abort
End Switch OK
Begin Switch BAD
End Switch BAD
```

but what I would expect is:

```
Begin Switch OK
Abort
End Switch OK
Begin Switch BAD
Abort
End Switch BAD
```

[Edited to be clearer about what I'm asking]
In other words, what kind of parsing mode is it in when parsing the case values that it does not recognize typed enum constants???

Thanks.

Edit: Keith's second-to-last comment in the checked answer below is the "answer".  His other comments are useful.  Thanks.

Comment: And what do you find if you add the parentheses to the BAD switch?

Comment: Works fine of course - the only difference between the two switches is the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bruce mentions, you need to add parens around the type specifier in the bad switch e.g.:

```
function weird()
{
    $l_ret= [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Abort
    "Begin Switch OK"
    switch( $l_ret )
    {
        ([System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Abort)  { 'Abort'  }
        ([System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel) { 'Cancel' }
    }
    "End Switch OK"
    "Begin Switch BAD"
    switch( $l_ret )
    {
        ([System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Abort)  { 'Abort'  }
        ([System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel) { 'Cancel' }
    }
    "End Switch BAD"
}
```

Otherwise PowerShell just interprets that information as a string and not a type specifier. It operates this way so switching on simple string tokens is, well, simple e.g.:

```
$var = "bar"
switch ($var) {
    foo { "foo" }
    bar { "bar" }
}
```

It is also typical for switch statements to operate on literal values instead of expressions.  PowerShell allows you to use expressions but you typically specify expressions with a scriptblock `{...}`.  It appears PowerShell accepts parens as well (evals the expression to the literal to match).  This is most inline with PowerShell's command parsing mode.

FWIW I will note that the help on switch is a bit misleading:

```
followed by
   {
       "string"|number|variable|{ expression } { statementlist }
       default { statementlist }
   }
```

This would seem to indicate that string literals must be quoted when they clearly don't need to be. Well, except when the string contains spaces or other punctuation like `{`, `;`, etc.

BTW this shortened version works:

```
    switch( $l_ret )
    {
        Abort  { 'Abort'  }
        Cancel { 'Cancel' }
    }
```

PowerShell knows how to coerce a field name of an enum to the enum type if it knows what the expected enum type is.  It is unfortunate that PowerShell can't do that, at least in this case, for the fully specified name.

Comment: But of course.  That's what I'm asking - why does it parse the case values as strings and not the enums?

Comment: As we know, `$var = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel` will not create a string $var.  What parsing mode is it in when parsing the case values?  I guess that's what I'm asking.

Comment: For reference, Keith's help refers to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847750.aspx. Also, note that the syntax `(expr) {statementList}` would not be equivalent to `{expr} {statementList}`. The former executes the `{statementList}` when the value of `(expr)` equals the case value, as my sample shows. The latter executes the `{statementList}` when the value of `expr` is true.

Comment: In effect, introducing the `()` changes the parsing mode from some mode that parses `[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel` as a string to a more normal parsing mode that correctly parses the enum expression. Not at all clear from the MS documentation.

Comment: And I guess I was asking is, what the heck is the parsing mode that is used to parse the case values, and WHY is it some special parsing mode????

Comment: Take a look at "Item 7: Understanding PowerShell Parsing Modes" in this PDF https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=5A8D2641E0963A97&resid=5A8D2641E0963A97%216929&app=WordPdf&wdo=1

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh So in the `()` case that also points to Command parsing mode e.g. `write-host get-date` spits out `get-date`.  If you want the result of get-date output you would execute `write-host (get-date)`.

Comment: IMHO, this answer should be rephrased. (1) It doesn't directly answer the question. (2) With fast reading, it may give wrong impression that `{[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Abort} {'Abort'}` way will work (it won't). Comments (of both David I. McIntosh and Keith Hill) are **very** helpful, but they should be included into the answer.